# Tableau + S3: Download file from S3 bucket through tableau

Tags: amazon-s3, tableau-api

I have **image files** stored in an S3 bucket and I want to connect tableau to S3 and provide visibility to see what files are in S3 and able to download ones that I am interested via Tableau. If this is possible, please point me to the tutorial so that I can further find out more the info and follow the steps.

Note: As a result of the files being images, so, connecting Tableau via Athena does not seem to meet the requirements.

Comment: Tableau cannot connect to image files as a data source. I think you need a different tool/programming language for this.

Comment: @bensw how did you go about it? Even i'm looking to download s3 log files via tableau

Comment: @DJ_Stuffy_K My data were CSV files. So I ended up loading them into relational database instead. :/